# Windows - Map shared folder as drive in non-local computer

Tags: windows, networking, security, file-sharing

is possible to map shared folder from server to clients computer as a drive without making VPN or simmilar complicated technologies, i'm using iis ftp publishing service extension for IIS on server and FtpDrive application on client computers, but it works not well.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

I tried open Samba ports on server and connect share via \serverdomain.com\share with my username and but it not works. In eventlog was error like "user Guest is blocked" .. Is there any problem with configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is confusing.  You can always map a drive to a shared folder, as long as you have access to that folder at the time inwhich the mapping is being accessed/established.

The VPN should only be necessary when the the shared drive is not on the local network and requires additional steps in-order to bring up the that connection to appear as being on their local network.....where it can then be mapped to a drive letter.

If the Drive letter is not necessary, but instead the ability to browse through the ftp site as if it were a local drive then you can follow these instructions: http://www.ghacks.net/2006/08/03/how-to-mount-an-ftp-drive-in-windows/, which describes how to attach a site as a NetHood link which can then be browsed in Windows Explorer, but please note these type of directories are not accessible to a cmd.exe or something similar because there is not a true mount being made when doing this.

Comment: yes sorry, i have it in title, but not in the question. client is not in local network. I know how to connect network location, but the main problem is, that you canť save direct to network location e.g. from "Save dialog" in Word. Employees want mapped drive for easy access and control..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using FTP, you could do this over http (or https if you need the encryption). All you need to do is enable WebDAV on the virtual folder in IIS. With Webdav you can map a drive letter to a nonlocal resource.

Answer (score 0):

VPN are not *inherently* complicated... and a VPN seems simpler to me than trying to masquerade an FTP as a network share.

I know this is not an answer to your original question but if the problem is mapping a remote share, personally I'd really try the VPN path with some simplified very-easy-to-use software such as [Hamachi](http://hamachi.cc/): that's what I use to VPN with people that would be scared of the word "VPN" such as my grandparents (yes, I need a VPN with them, to fix or upgrade their computer remotely via RemoteDesktop ^_^).

As easy as "yes, download that link I sent you... yes double-click there, yes wait a bit, ok now write this password, ok, accept that dialog... ok, I see you, youre'set!" (well ok, just a tiny bit more complex than that, but really little)

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, I wouldn't expose ports to the internet that are required for file sharing.

I second Hamachi.